# Wordpress Error Log not working. The site is experiencing technical difficulties

Tags: php, wordpress, error-log

I am a working on custom wordpress plugin i need to show php errors.

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

@ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Tried above but still getting this message :(

```
The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
```

Not errors

Comment: Please Check remove by your last added Code or plugin. its create this type of error. Check in your email also.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable this behavior by setting `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` to `true`:

```
define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true );
```

This will stop the "The site is experiencing technical difficulties" message from appearing, so errors will appear as they did prior to this feature being added.

Comment: Thank so much.. now i am getting white screen :(

Comment: Disabling error displaying will make the debugging more harder

Comment: Reloading apache service some how solved the issue for me.